# Postfix delivers messages locally despite configuration for discovering external agent

Tags: email, dns, smtp, postfix, sendmail

A small node operates several web applications attached to a domain.

The same domain is used for mailboxes, hosted off site by a commercial service.

On the name server operated by the registrar, *A*, *AAAA*, and *CNAME* records are used to resolve the web server, whereas *MX* records are used to resolve the commercial mail service.

Applications on the web server must deliver mail addressed within the same domain.

Postfix runs on the server, and correctly transfers messages for addresses of other domains based on resolving their *MX* records. However, messages detected as addressed for a local domain are not transferred to external delivery agents, but rather retained for local delivery, despite that the *MX* records for the domain give an alternative domain corresponding to the commercial service.

The [documentation for Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydestination) suggests that the desired behavior may be realized by setting a value for the configuration parameter `mydestination` that excludes as an item in the value list `$mydomain`.

An [answer posted elsewhere on the StackExchange network](https://serverfault.com/a/854108/589665) gives a similar suggestion, of setting the configuration as follows:

```
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
```

In fact, such is the actual value currently set, being the default provided by the software stack operating on the host.

Given that the assigned local domain is not included in the criteria for identifying addresses for local delivery of messages, why are messages addressed within the local domain nonetheless still being locally delivered?